# How do I get a Flask Application to run on a Subpage?

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I have a flask app running on port 5000 but that port is blocked on my server and I can't unblock it. Ideally I'd like to just run the app on www.mywebsite.com/flaskapp, is this possible by just configuring apache2? The rest of the server is essentially a wordpress website and I'd like to not destroy that to run this flask app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using mod_wsgi on Apache2.

If you have a graphing app you only want to run on /graph, add this to your virtual host config:

WSGIScriptAlias /graph /var/www/graph/graph.wsgi

Navigating to /graph and it'll run the .wsgi you've written for it.

Comment: Do I not need to put that as a separate site with a seperate conf file?

Comment: What would the graph.wsgi file look like?

Comment: For a flask web app, it's just importing your python code for it. The standard implementation being:
"from graph import graph_app as application"

The config goes in whichever virtual host you're configuring the app for.